# How To Know If a URL Is A Page or Post or Category WordPress

Tags: wordpress

How can I know whether a specific Wordpress url is a page, category or post? I am setting up a website with articles to be categorized similar to that on hawaii.com.

Using this example, if we take the category  'Vacation Packages', we find under it a listing of the various islands. Are these pages or posts? example: **www.hawaii.com/oahu/vacation-packages/**. Also, is **www.hawaii.com/oahu/** a page or post? I realize that this website is structured so that under each island, you can find links to the various categories such as **www.hawaii.com/oahu/attractions/** and **www.hawaii.com/oahu/accommodations/**. How can I create this same structure?

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: [Conditional Tags](https://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags)

Answer (score 0):

I used the plugin 'Post Tags and Categories for Pages' instead. This plugin adds the stock WordPress categories for all of your pages. Pages will show up in the stock WordPress archive queries.

Also see: http://spicemailer.com/wordpress/add-categories-tags-pages-wordpress/